# Correct way to write $ AB$ is not defined

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology

What's the correct way to write that a functions is not defined?

e.g.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\text{is not defined}
 $$

or 
$$
\frac10 \text{is undefined} $$

Comment: That's a matrix and a vector, not a function.  I'd typically say something like "The dot (or inner) product is not defined between a matrix and a vector."  (Assuming that's what you mean.)

Comment: The title, on the other hand, makes no use of a centered dot, and that seems to focus attention on whether a matrix product is defined.

Comment: @hardmath $ \cdot $ gone.  I think I should have just written $ \frac10 $ instead.

Comment: @BrianTung, Every matrix represents a linear transformation, so calling it a function should be OK.

Comment: @Justin: I thought of that, but it didn't read like that to me.  I'll chalk it up to my misreading it.

Comment: @BrianTung, Nah, I think you read it fine. There's a weird gray area of viewing matrices as arrays and as linear transformations, but both are formally different.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply write a sentence. "The product is undefined."

Comment: That's embarrassing.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's still defined in your edit.

Comment: Thanks!  It's late.  Brain's not in gear.

Comment: No worries. Keep working hard.